# Redirect from old domain to new domain with dynamic query string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, dns

I want to redirect old domain url to new domain with dynamic query string

My htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^en.olddomain.com$ [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.en.olddomain.com$ [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^en.olddomain.com/$1$
 RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

It's working for redirect all urls with query string to new url

But i also want to change the pattern of query string like

My old urls like

> http://en.olddomain.com/product?g=any_value

I want to redirect some of them to

> http://www.newdomain.com/en/product/any_value/

Or some of them to

> http://www.newdomain.com/en/product/

I added these lines in htaccess to redirect with dynamic query string

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^g=(.*)
 RewriteRule ^http://www.newdomain.com/en/product/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

But it's not working

Comment: Are both domains being served from the same folder on the same machine by the same webserver process ? Is `mod_rewrite` enabled ?  Are there any other rules in your `.htaccess` file before or after this ? Is there an `.htaccess` in a folder above this ?  Is this in the root of the website folder ?

Comment: @KraangPrime i don't have too much information about server it is client's domain so i made again the old domain to the server and added htaccess to it now can you tell me how to pass query string to redirect ? en.olddomain.com/product?g=any_value redirect to http://www.newdomain.com/en/product/ebony/any_value

Comment: @KraangPrime i have edited my question can you please help me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Your last rewrite condition always returns false as you are matching against url path using http host header. To redirect old domain urls and to manipulate query strings you can use the following rule

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^g=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^ http://newdomain.com/en/product/%1 [L,R]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R]
```